# First and last day of a month

Tags: date, calendar

Given two numbers, month and year, how can I compute the first and the last day of that month ? My goal is to output these three lines:

1. month / year (month in textual form but that is trivial)
2. for each day of the month: name of the day of the week for the current day: Fri. & Sat. & Sun. [...]
3. day number within the month: 1 & 2 & 3 [...] &  28 & .. ?

I'm looking for a solution using GNU `date` or BSD `date` (on OS X).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some time ago I had similar issue. There is my solution:

```bsh
 $ ./get_dates.sh 2012 07
The first day is 01.2012.07, Sunday
The last day is 31.2012.07, Tuesday
 $ cal
 July 2012
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7
 8  9 10 11 12 13 14
15 16 17 18 19 20 21
22 23 24 25 26 27 28
29 30 31
```

Script itself:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# last day for month
lastday()  {
#                ja   fe   ma   ap   ma   jn   jl   ag   se   oc   no   de
  mlength=('xx' '31' '28' '31' '30' '31' '30' '31' '31' '30' '31' '30' '31')

  year=$1
  month=$2

  if [ $month -ne 2 ] ; then
    echo ${mlength[$month]}
    return 0
  fi

  leap=0
  ((!(year%100))) && { ((!(year%400))) && leap=1 ; } || { ((!(year%4))) && leap=1 ; }

  feblength=28
  ((leap)) && feblength=29
  echo $feblength
}

# date to Julian date
date2jd() {

  year=$1
  month=$2
  day=$3
  lday=$(lastday $year $month) || exit $?

  if ((day<1 || day> lday)) ; then
    echo day out of range
    exit 1
  fi

  echo $(( jd = day - 32075
                + 1461 * (year + 4800 - (14 - month)/12)/4
                        + 367 * (month - 2 + (14 - month)/12*12)/12
                    - 3 * ((year + 4900 - (14 - month)/12)/100)/4
                - 2400001 ))
}

jd2dow()
{
  days=('Sunday' 'Monday' 'Tuesday' 'Wednesday' 'Thursday' 'Friday' 'Saturday')

  jd=$1
  if ((jd<1 || jd>782028)) ; then
    echo julian day out of range
    return 1
  fi

  ((dow=(jd+3)%7))

  echo ${days[dow]}
}


echo -n "The first day is 01.$1.$2, "
jd2dow $(date2jd $1 $2 01)
echo -n "The last day is $(lastday $1 $2).$1.$2, "
jd2dow $(date2jd $1 $2 $(lastday $1 $2))
```

I didn't have GNU `date` on machines I need it, therefore I didn't solve it with date. May be there is more beautiful solution.

Answer (score 23):

```bash
# Last month:
l_first_date=$(date -d "`date +%Y%m01` -1 month" +%Y-%m-%d)
l_last_date=$(date -d "`date +%Y%m01` -1 day" +%Y-%m-%d)

# This month:
t_first_date=$(date +%Y-%m-01)
t_last_date=$(date -d "`date +%Y%m01` +1 month -1 day" +%Y-%m-%d)

# Next month:
n_first_date=$(date -d "`date +%Y%m01` +1 month" +%Y-%m-%d)
n_last_date=$(date -d "`date +%Y%m01` +2  month -1 day" +%Y-%m-%d)

# Print everything
echo "Last month: $l_first_date to $l_last_date"
echo "This month: $t_first_date to $t_last_date"
echo "Next month: $n_first_date to $n_last_date"
```

Comment: Pure gold, the nested `date` is perfect in cron one-liners. thanks! Please note also the nested `$()` will work e.g. `d=$(date -d "$(date +%Y%m01) -3 month" +%Y-%m-%d`

Answer (score 8):

I'll be honest; from the way you're asking the question I get the sense you've been assigned some homework, so I'll leave a few steps out of the answer as an exercise for the reader:

You'll want to take a good look at the `date` manual page; especially the `-d` flag, which allows you to examine any given day. The first day of month M in year Y would be "M/01/Y"

Getting the *last* day of the month, your best bet is to add 1 to the number of the month you were given, then deduct one day in the date.

Hint: `date` can actually accept some extensive arithmetic; I can, for instance, say `date -d "01/07/2012 + 1 month - 1 day"` and it will give me the correct answer.

You can find out how to display the output you want in 2) and 3) by studying the "format" section of the `date` manpage.

Hints: Look at `%a` and `%d`

Comment: The `+"format string"` parameter to date will also be helpful here, e.g. `date -d "01/07/2012 + 1 month - 1 day" +"%d"`

Answer (score 3):

```
date -d "20121101 + 1 month - 1 day" +%Y%m%d
```

Comment: At least you should specify which of the question's 3 points are answered by your code.

Answer (score 3):

### **Previous Month Start and End date**

```bsh
month_year=$(date +'%m %Y' | awk '!--$1{$1=12;$2--}1')
m=${month_year% *}
y=${month_year##* }
d=$(cal $m $y | paste -s - | awk '{print $NF}')
first_date=$(printf '01-%02s-%s' $m $y)
last_date=$(printf '%s-%02s-%s' $d $m $y)
echo $first_date $last_date
```

### **Current Month Start and End date**

```bsh
month_year=$(date +'%m %Y' | awk '!$1{$1=12;$2--}1')
m=${month_year% *}
y=${month_year##* }
d=$(cal $m $y | paste -s - | awk '{print $NF}')
first_date=$(printf '01-%02s-%s' $m $y)
last_date=$(printf '%s-%02s-%s' $d $m $y)
echo $first_date $last_date
```

### **Next Month Start and End date**

```bsh
month_year=$(date +'%m %Y' | awk '!++$1{$1=12;$2--}1')
m=${month_year% *}
y=${month_year##* }
d=$(cal $m $y | paste -s - | awk '{print $NF}')
first_date=$(printf '01-%02s-%s' $m $y)
last_date=$(printf '%s-%02s-%s' $d $m $y)
echo $first_date $last_date
```